# Git add permission denied ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, permissions

My application is hosted on ubuntu in public_html folder. When I run the command `git add .` it gives me the error:

```
warning: could not open directory 'public_html/': Permission denied
```

Entire code is in `public_html` folder

How can I solve it?

Comment: Open a terminal and go to the parent folder for public_html and type `ls -al` make sure that the folder isn't restricted to root.  If it is restricted and it's safe to change permissions, do so.  If not, move the application to a non-restricted folder

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure so that your user has access or is the owner of the folder and it content. You can check the current owner and permissions by running:

```
ls -l public_html
```

Here I list all non-hidden files in a test folder:

```
who:test who$ ls -l 
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  admin  0 Oct  3 18:04 test1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  admin  0 Oct  3 18:04 test2
```

The output shows that both files are owned by the `root` user and belongs to a group named `admin`. The first column also shows the access permission, which in this case is set to read and write access to everyone.

If you would like to change the owner you can do:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> public_html
```

The above will set the owner of the folder and all its content to the specified user and group; you might need sudo privileges to do this.

There is possible to only change the owner or group with the same command:

```
sudo chown -R <user> public_html
sudo chown -R :<group> public_html
```

To change the permission you would use:

```
sudo chmod -R <mode> public_html
```

Where mode is the permission, for instance `0777` for full read and write access to everyone. You can also use letters instead of an octal number when setting permissions, for instance:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx public_html
```

gives the same result as the first `chmod` command.

**References**

- The chown command: https://ss64.com/bash/chown.html
- The chmod command: https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html